# How to get the value if the value is present in the xlsx sheet without knowing index number?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx, xlrd

I have a unstructured Xslx file. I want to get the full row if the values are present in the sheet. For example

```
A     B    C    D   F  

abc  10   24   32   54
cdf  9    10   34   98
mgl  11   90   21   98
fgd  1    9     2   10
```

I want to get if the 10 value present in the sheet to get the full row values

output =>

```
abc  10   24   32   54

cdf  9    10   34   98

fgd  1    9     2   10
```

thanks for the contributions

Comment: You should always include the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one `True` per rows:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

df1 = df[df.eq(10).any(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[(df == 10).any(axis=1)]

print (df1)
     A   B   C   D   F
0  abc  10  24  32  54
1  cdf   9  10  34  98
3  fgd   1   9   2  10
```

Comment: how to get the last value only like 54,98,10

Comment: @Dev - You can use `print (df1['F'])` or `print (df1.iloc[:, -1])`

Comment: sorry to ask this question i have a output like this NaN    b'5,806.65 \n        5,806.65 \n       11,613.30'  i need to get last value only dtype is object  output like 11,613.30

Comment: @Dev - What is corect output?

Comment: 11,613.30 is output

Comment: Not `11613.30` is expected output?

Comment: no i get the value of last  column but in this column present more values so i need to get last value

Comment: @Dev - Do you think`print (df1.iloc[-1, -1])` ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand my input now. previous your answer is correct that's no problem. now I had last column values is fine but in this column contain three line values so i need last line value only

Comment: @Dev - `last = df1.iloc[:, -1]` and then `print (last.iloc[-1])` ?

Comment: it raises an error like: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: @Dev - hmm, not changed `last` to some another variable?

Comment: can you give the social network id I want to follow you for my knowledge development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207058/discussion-between-jezrael-and-dev).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) followed by [pandas.DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df[df.isin([10]).any(axis = 1)]

   A    B   C   D   F
0   abc 10  24  32  54
1   cdf 9   10  34  98
3   fgd 1   9   2   10
```